# PhpStorm Typo3 setup for testing - TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity not found

Tags: typo3, phpstorm

I am trying to develop my first own extension for Typo3. I have limited or nearly none knowledge on PHP but first want to setup the extension structure and files needed.

I use PhpStorm on my Windows client. T3 is installed on a Linux server. Connection via SSH - which works.

I have setup my project in PhpStorm and linked it to the related directory of the extension on the server. Deployment of edited files works fine.

In some (most) PHP files I have some use statements e.g.

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;
```

Already when editing I get the error:

```
Undefined namespace 'Controller'
```

My understanding of this is that PhpStorm cannot find the related class somewhere in the code of all files of the project. This is, from my perspective, correct, since these files are only on the server. I guess, I could ignore these type of error messages.

But

When trying to run some tests I get

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity" not found in ---- path of the server for the php file.
```

It looks to me as if I need to tell the PhpStorm something more about the servers setup, specially the `vendor` directory and all classes in there.

But how?

Comment: If you want to develop and test on your local machine, you should have the complete project locally, too. Just having the extension locally wouldn't work with testing.

Comment: I'd suggest to setup the complete TYPO3 on your local machine. There are several ways to get it running fast, e.g. with ddev.

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHPStorm. It is very difficult to start creating TYPO3 Extensions if you have as you say almost none knowledge of PHP. I would recommend that you first learn a basic PHP, and then the MVC system which TYPO3 uses for the extensions. Once you know that, you will find it 100 times easier to understand it. Invest on learning first. The errors that you have could be anything, from wrong namespaces to misconfiguration or wrong TYPO3 installation path. Is it composer? Is it via zip? There is a lot to take into consideration

Comment: *"Undefined namespace 'Controller'"* PhpStorm needs to index that file. Just copy all the code files locally (so the IDE can see and index them), even if you will not be running the code on your local machine.

Comment: If you have no knowledge of PHP and probably of TYPO3 you should use the `ExtensionBuilder` for new extensions as it generates a logical working stub. Testing from PHPStorm can be done only if you have TYPO3 local as the whole system is neccessary for testing. And last: if you create a new extension it is known to TYPO3 only if you activate the extension (either with composer or in BE module)

Comment: *"When trying to run some tests I get"* Not using Typo3 so cannot advise here. But sounds like PHP Interpreter or deployment is not set up completely (**assuming** that you are trying to use PHPUnit tests (or whatever supported tech that is) using the IDE functionality: the IDE needs to know how to map local paths to remote ones, and in some cases you need to actually specify the remote path and not local (sorry, cannot really help on this one)

Comment: is there anywhere a somehow good and complete howto? I have had a look at most of the t3 documentation. There is a small hint on phpstorm to use, but no setup with windows client and T3 linux server. I don't have the intention to add a GUI to my server (GNOME...) and do the development completely on the linux mashine.

Comment: @averlon *"I don't have the intention to add a GUI to my server (GNOME...) and do the development completely on the linux mashine."* What about without adding a GUI? In general: https://www.jetbrains.com/remote-development/gateway/  PhpStorm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-development-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

solution is not to run the tests as PHP-Test but as PHPUnit-Tests on the remote Server.

Then it works!
In my case PHPUnit was already setup on the remote server and inside PHPstorm settings.
I just startet the test the wrong way as a local test - which naturally did not work.